# PHP API - Unable to query fields in custom objects

Tags: soap-api, php

I'm trying to query for information using the PHP API (v20) and I am unable to query any custom object fields. The only one that appears to work is Id. It gives no error, in fact, the query itself works. It only returns the Id, whether or not I queried for it. Though, if I had not queried for it then the Id field is blank.

The following is a sample of what I get back from a query. I tried updating the enterprise.wsdl.xml to one tailored to my Org, but it still doesn't work. Is there something I am missing? I'm not aware of any place I can view logs of what took place (like you do with the bulk api on yourorg.my.salesforce.com/750).

```
QueryResult Object (
    [queryLocator] => 
    [done] => 1 
    [records] => Array (
        [0] => SObject Object (
            [type] =>
            [fields] =>
            [Id] => SFIDHERE
        )
    )
    [size] => 1
)
```

Sample of the query run that produces the above. (line breaks added for less scroll)

```
$results = $mySforceConnection->query(
    "SELECT Id, Name, Stage__c, Subtotal__c FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE AccountId = '$Id'"
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the partner WSDL. Please note that you have to put this to URL like `http://yourServer/yourPartnerWsdl.xml` - it won't work using a local path like `/var/www/whatever/yourPartnerWsdl.xml`

You will get errors directly in PHP. Therfore your Error settings has to be set in php.ini to something like

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

which might not be the default.

The following code should work after adjusting your paths

```
require_once ('../yourPathTo/soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php');
define("USERNAME", "you@wherever.com");
define("PASSWORD", "yourPassword");
define("SECURITY_TOKEN", "yourToken");
$GLOBALS[sfBatchSize] = 100;
$GLOBALS[sfConnection] = new SforcePartnerClient();
$GLOBALS[sfConnection]->createConnection("http://yourServer/yourPartnerWsdl.xml");
$GLOBALS[sfConnection]->setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/31.0');
$GLOBALS[sfConnection]->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);

$query = "SELECT Metier__c, Profil__c, Secteur__c, TypeContrat__c, Id FROM Opportunity ";
$response = $GLOBALS[sfConnection]->query($query);
$records = $response->records;
while(!$response->done) {
    $response = $GLOBALS[sfConnection]->queryMore($response->queryLocator);
    $records = array_merge($records, $response->records);    
}
print_r($records);
```

Comment: You are simply amazing. Thank you, Uwe Heim! I would upvote you, but I don't have the points yet...

Comment: If it was helpful you might consider to upvote the question. Glad this worked for you. I did many years primarily PHP before I started with Salesforce and I'm happy to to assist, if I can. - I see - then come back later :-)

Comment: I'm just curious: which of the points mention was it in the end? I was only fishing for possible reasons. Could you drill it down?

Comment: Sorry, got my terms mixed. I didn't have enough rep, but do now. Upvoted you.

I switched to Partner from Enterprise. Once I did that and did the createConnection() as you prescribed as well as the setEndpoint(), it worked magnificently.